# How can I implement options menu inside a layout like in Google Play

Tags: android

I would like to know how to effectively and efficiently implement options menu inside a layout like the one used in Google Play market (Such the one in the image bellow)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Creating a floating context menu part

Comment: I couldn't find what I am looking for in the link you provided. As the menu should be in a layout or a Widget View.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a `PopMenu` which displays on `Click` event.
Here is a good tutorial: [Creating a Popup Menu in Android](http://subinsebastien.tumblr.com/post/34083607792/creating-a-popup-menu-in-android).
See the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu).